# Streaming data to .csv not showing results C#

Tags: c#, sql-server, streamwriter, data-stream

I am attempting to stream data from a SQLServer DB to a .CSV file; However, after execution, the .csv is still blank. The first while loop is/was for testing purposes which executed correctly. I know I am doing something wrong in my Streaming portion.

Any help is greatly appreciated!

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Data.SqlClient;
using System.Diagnostics;
using System.IO;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace ConsoleApp1
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection("Server=*******;Database=*********;Integrated Security=true");
            conn.Open();
            SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("SELECT p.cFName, p.cLName, s.cSugTitle, s.cEcrno, g.cName, h.mNotes, u.UserID, u.NetworkID FROM people p INNER JOIN suggest s ON p.cidPeople = s.cidPeople_WhoEntered INNER JOIN Grp g on s.cidGrp = g.cidGrp INNER JOIN history h ON h.cidSuggest = s.cidSuggest INNER JOIN users u ON u.cidPeople = p.cidPeople", conn);
            SqlDataReader reader = cmd.ExecuteReader();

        while (reader.Read())
        {
            Console.WriteLine("{0}, {1}, {2}, {3}, {4}, {5}, {6}, {7}", reader.GetString(0), reader.GetString(1), reader.GetString(2), reader.GetString(3), reader.GetString(4), reader.IsDBNull(5) ? null : reader.GetString(5), reader.GetString(6), reader.IsDBNull(7) ? null : reader.GetString(7));
        }


        String path = @"C:\Users\AEEVANS\Desktop\example.csv";

        using (StreamWriter sr = File.AppendText(path))
        {
            while (reader.Read())
            {
                sr.WriteLine("{0}, {1}, {2}, {3}, {4}, {5}, {6}, {7}", reader.GetString(0), reader.GetString(1), reader.GetString(2), reader.GetString(3), reader.GetString(4), reader.IsDBNull(5) ? null : reader.GetString(5), reader.GetString(6), reader.IsDBNull(7) ? null : reader.GetString(7));
                sr.Close();
            }  
        }
        Console.ReadKey();

        reader.Close();
        conn.Close();

        if (Debugger.IsAttached)
        {
            Console.ReadLine();
        }
    }
  }
}
```

**EDIT**
I have edited my original code to not include the first while loop per recommendation. I am now running into the following error:

> System.ObjectDisposedException: 'Cannot write to a closed TextWriter.'

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Data.SqlClient;
using System.Diagnostics;
using System.IO;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace ConsoleApp1
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection("Server=********;Database=*********;Integrated Security=true");
            conn.Open();
            SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("SELECT p.cFName, p.cLName, s.cSugTitle, s.cEcrno, g.cName, h.mNotes, u.UserID, u.NetworkID FROM people p INNER JOIN suggest s ON p.cidPeople = s.cidPeople_WhoEntered INNER JOIN Grp g on s.cidGrp = g.cidGrp INNER JOIN history h ON h.cidSuggest = s.cidSuggest INNER JOIN users u ON u.cidPeople = p.cidPeople", conn);
            SqlDataReader reader = cmd.ExecuteReader();

            String path = @"C:\Users\AEEVANS\Desktop\example.csv";

            using (StreamWriter sr = File.AppendText(path))
            {
                while (reader.Read())
                {
                    sr.WriteLine("{0}, {1}, {2}, {3}, {4}, {5}, {6}, {7}", reader.GetString(0), reader.GetString(1), reader.GetString(2), reader.GetString(3), reader.GetString(4), reader.IsDBNull(5) ? null : reader.GetString(5), reader.GetString(6), reader.IsDBNull(7) ? null : reader.GetString(7));
                    sr.Close();
                }
            }

            reader.Close();
            conn.Close();

            if (Debugger.IsAttached)
            {
                Console.ReadLine();
            }

        }
        }
    }
```

Comment: After your first loop (reader.Read(), the reader is at EOF. That's why your second loop doesn't do anything. Get rid of the first loop. You also should wrap the connection, command and reader in using blocks.

Comment: Also closing the Streamwriter inside the loop will let you with just one record in your file. If you have more records you will never see them while an exception will be raised at the second loop when you try to write to a closed stream

Answer (score 3):

`while (reader.Read())` is a one-way trip through a data reader.  If you do another `while (reader.Read())`, you'll get nothing because the pointer is already at the end of the reader's contents.

Looks like you should be able to combine  your two `while (reader.Read())` blocks into one.

Comment: I removed my first while loop per recommendation. I am now receiving the following error: System.ObjectDisposedException: 'Cannot write to a closed TextWriter.'

Comment: After my sr.WriteLine ();

Comment: That's because of what Steve said in his comment.   You need to move `sr.Close` AFTER the `while (reader.Read())` block.

Comment: Do not know how I missed that. Thanks!